# How to obtain the encoder from the make_csv_dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I used this code from the tutorial:

```
def get_train_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):
  dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      file_path,
      batch_size=10, # Artificially small to make examples easier to show.
      label_name=LABEL_COLUMN,
      na_value="?",
      num_epochs=1,
      ignore_errors=True,
      select_columns= CSV_COLUMNS,
      **kwargs)
  return dataset
```

Then I created the train set:

```
raw_train_data = get_train_dataset(train_file_path)
```

to train the model.

The question is how to get the encoder used for the training data for encoding new text?

I loaded the new data, but this doesn't use the same encoder as the training data:

```
raw_test_data = get_test_dataset(new_data_file_path)
```

How to obtain the original encoder when using tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset?

EDIT:

```
    train_file_path = "./train.csv"
test_file_path = "./test.csv"

LABEL_COLUMN = 'target'
CSV_COLUMNS = ['text', 'target']

def get_train_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):
  dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      file_path,
      batch_size=10, # Artificially small to make examples easier to show.
      label_name=LABEL_COLUMN,
      na_value="?",
      num_epochs=1,
      ignore_errors=True,
      select_columns= CSV_COLUMNS,
      **kwargs)
  return dataset

def get_test_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):
  dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      file_path,
      batch_size=10, # Artificially small to make examples easier to show.
      na_value="?",
      num_epochs=1,
      ignore_errors=True,
      **kwargs)
  return dataset

sample_submission = pd.read_csv("./sample_submission.csv")

raw_train_data = get_train_dataset(train_file_path)
raw_test_data = get_test_dataset(test_file_path)

def extract_train_tensor(example, label):
    print(example)
    return example['text'], label

def extract_test_tensor(example):
    print(example)
    return example['text']

test_data = raw_test_data.map(lambda ex: extract_test_tensor(ex))
test_data_size = len(list(test_data))
print("test size: ", test_data_size)

train_data_all = raw_train_data.map(lambda ex, label: extract_train_tensor(ex, label))
train_data_all = train_data_all.shuffle(10000)
print(train_data_all)
train_data_size = len(list(train_data_all))
print("train size: ", train_data_size)
train_size = int(0.7 * train_data_size)
val_size = int(0.3 * train_data_size)
train_data = train_data_all.take(train_size)
val_data = train_data_all.skip(train_size)

embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[],
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_data,
                    epochs=20,
                    validation_data=val_data,
                    verbose=1)
import numpy as np
predictions = model.predict(test_data)
predictions = np.where(predictions > 0.5, 1, 0)
sample_submission['target'] = predictions
print(predictions)
```

The two calls to get_train_dataset() and get_test_dataset() to generate train and test data. The train data is split into train and validation sets and the accuracy is great. However, the test data accuracy is very low. Both data sets are strings of text and I didn't do any encoding.

Comment: What do you mean under "encoder"?

Comment: Test data also needs to be turned into integers, right? And they have to be converted in the same scheme as the training data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset?version=stable) does not make any encoding.
It is about:

> Reads CSV files into a dataset, where each element is a (features,
>   labels) tuple that corresponds to a batch of CSV rows. The features
>   dictionary maps feature column names to Tensors containing the
>   corresponding feature data, and labels is a Tensor containing the
>   batch's label data.

So your `get_test_dataset()` function should not care about the `get_train_dataset()` function dataset generation procedure.

**Regarding the low test performance:**

You trained and validated your model with random combination of samples of the same data with repetition:

```
train_data = train_data_all.take(train_size)
val_data = train_data_all.skip(train_size)
```

Thus probably you will have identical samples in them, so your validation will not resulted in a real measurement of the accuracy of model.

In contrary the model never saw the test set's samples, so prediction on this set is a reliable measurement of performance.

Comment: Hi, Geeocode, the reason I thought 'make_csv_dataset' does the encoding automatically is that with the train_data read by this function, I split it into train and validation set, and sent it to model to train, the validation accuracy is nearly 97%. It's a binary classification on text data. So the data type is string and I didn't do any encoding.

Comment: However, when I used the 'predict' to perform predictions, the accuracy is only 70%. Again, I didn't perform any encoding for the new test data. I had thought it's due to different encodings with the 2 calls of 'make_csv_dataset' to load the train and test data individually.  Why does the model perform so well on validation data even without any conversion of string to integer? And why did it perform badly on test data which isn't encoded as well? I added some code to it to give more context.

Comment: Hi @ling Ok I looked into it, but where you define the valid_data as it is important me to be able to find the reason.

Comment: @ling see my amendments, what is the accuracy result on test data?

Comment: Lower than 70%. That's the suggested way of splitting train and val sets by TensorFlow tutorial. You mean the issue may be due to many identical samples in the data? However, that's not true. Also, I don't understand why without converting into numbers, the model still is able to train on string textual data.

Comment: @ling Please insert the tf tutorial you mentioned here. Answer to your second question: Because the inserted embedding stands for it i.e. it embeds the textual data into equal sized, related feature space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205048/discussion-between-ling-and-geeocode).